# Embed tag with invalid PDF source doesn't fire onerror

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple website with an embed element that loads a PDF. I want to show an error message to the user, if the PDF's source is invalid.

```html
    <embed src="test.pdf" onerror="showError('pdf')" type="application/pdf">
    <img src="test.png" onerror="showError('img')" alt="">

    <script>
        function showError(file) {
            console.log('failed to load ' + file);
        }
    </script>
```

In above example both sources `test.pdf` and `test.png` do not exist. As a result in the console I get two 404 errors as expected. But I only get 1 console logging from the missing image. It seems that the `onerror` event on the `<embed>` tag never fires.

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQk2t.png)

I also tried to attach event listeners manually to the `embed` tag and even a global listener to `window`. Both do not fire when the PDF source is invalid.

All of this is was tested in Chrome browser (Chromium 80).

Is there a way to listen to the `onerror` event in case of an invalid `src` without having to make a separate http request first to see if the source returns an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onerror supports only the following tags below.

```
<img> <input type="image"> <object> <link>  <script>
```

This, I suppose is the reason why the function is not firing on the embed tag.

Please see this link for further inquiry https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onerror.asp